# How do I block notifications from a specific person (or in general) in OSx on Skype?

Tags: skype

I have an office computer with Skype running on it, and some of the contacts are personal. I don't want the messages from them to appear on my screen or pop up on the top right, even when I am in Skype (talkign to someone else). Is that possible? I don't mind blocking it for all contacts, if necessary, though I would prefer to do it in a more refined way.

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Preferences > Notifications. There, find Skype from the list of Applications and choose it. Now, you should be able to customize what kind of push notifications (the alerts in the upper right corner), sound notifications, or dock badges you'd like to see, if any.